# Split a list every time the first element of a child list changes

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration

I have a list that looks like this

```
[[6, 4, 163, 42],
 [6, 44, 163, 79],
 [6, 80, 163, 118],
 [6, 119, 163, 156],
 [6, 158, 163, 187],
 [6, 192, 163, 225],
 [6, 231, 163, 265],
 [169, 4, 260, 42],
 [169, 44, 260, 79],
 [169, 80, 260, 118],
 [169, 119, 260, 156],
 [169, 158, 260, 187],
 [169, 192, 260, 225],
 [169, 231, 260, 265],
 [273, 4, 385, 42],
 [273, 44, 385, 79],
 [273, 80, 385, 118],
 [273, 119, 385, 156],
 [273, 158, 385, 187],
 [273, 192, 385, 225],
 [273, 231, 385, 265]
```

I am trying to split the list every time the first element of the child list changes

I am trying to get the list to become like this

```
[[[6, 4, 163, 42],
 [6, 44, 163, 79],
 [6, 80, 163, 118],
 [6, 119, 163, 156],
 [6, 158, 163, 187],
 [6, 192, 163, 225],
 [6, 231, 163, 265]],
 [[169, 4, 260, 42],
 [169, 44, 260, 79],
 [169, 80, 260, 118],
 [169, 119, 260, 156],
 [169, 158, 260, 187],
 [169, 192, 260, 225],
 [169, 231, 260, 265]],
 [[273, 4, 385, 42],
 [273, 44, 385, 79],
 [273, 80, 385, 118],
 [273, 119, 385, 156],
 [273, 158, 385, 187],
 [273, 192, 385, 225],
 [273, 231, 385, 265]]]
```

I am not sure how to do this

Comment: what code have you written?

Comment: *Hint:* Try setting up a `dict` with the keys `6`, `167`, and `273`, in other words element 0 of every sublist.

Answer (score 1):

how about something like this:

```
print([[i for i in lst if i[0] == k] for k in list(set([j[0] for j in lst]))])
```

where "lst" is the name of your original list

Comment: oneliners are tight

Comment: If one-liner is preferred (considered unreadable in most case),  let's choose some good variable names: ```print([[sublist for sublist in lst if sublist[0] == key] 
                for key in list(set([sub[0] 
        for sub in lst]))])